# impounded attachments -- what exactly are those?

Tags: meaning

Source: [The Illustrated Network—How TCP/IP Works in a Modern Network by Walter Goralski (2009)](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Illustrated_Network.html?id=6nDtNA6VJ5YC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> The modern email explosion has produced on-line ads, do-not-contact lists, spam, spam blockers, evil attachments, **impounded attachments**, and dozens of other moves and countermoves that make the email experience at once essential and yet daunting for many.

Not really sure what those are. Any idea?

Comment: An attachment is a file _attached_ to an email, like a graphic or PDF document. An attachment that is _impounded_ has been removed from the email by the receiving system, or has caused the email to which it is attached to be undelivered or quarantined for later inspection. OED has for "impound": _"To seize or secure by legal right; to take legal or formal possession of (a document or the like) to be held in custody of the law."_

Comment: I was going to answer this question, but it would just duplicate the comment by @P.E.Dant